# How does one define the media-type on Windows Phone 7 when using DownloadStringAsync method?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I am trying to download an XML file using the Store Wrapper API (http://zunderstorehost.azurewebsites.net/).

When I use WP8StoreApp, it shows as an XML file when viewed in Google Chrome.  However, when I use the same for Windows Phone, it returns a JSON instead.

Here's my code snippet:

```
WebClient twitter = new WebClient();
twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler
    (twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri
    ("http://zunderstorehost.azurewebsites.net/api/WP8StoreApp/Guid/0b792c7c-14dc-df11-a844-00237de2db9e"));
```

I understand that I have to specify the media type (application/xml), but I can't find examples.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is set the `Accept` header on the request to `application/xml`. Problem is: the `WebClient` class restricts access to a number of headers, as described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx).

Unfortunately, `Accept` is one of the restricted headers, so the documentation suggests to use the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class, which does allow setting the restricted headers. You can set the `Accept` header on your `HttpWebRequest` instance as follows:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://example.com"));
request.Accept = "application/xml";
```

The code project has a good example on how to use `HttpWebRequest`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156610/WP-WebClient-vs-HttpWebRequest